# Where can I access the link-validation review queue?

Tags: support, review, broken-link

Today, I [reviewed a post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/links/1387537) in a review queue named link validation review queue. It's very newer to me. I didn't heard this before. I got that review link from [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212021/question-tagged-for-link-validation-with-no-highlighted-links) post.

After reviewing, when I click next button, it shows a message that there are no items to review.

[image]
[image]

After sometime, when I load that [review url](https://stackoverflow.com/review/links), it shows page not found. I can't understand.

Comment: Maybe it's an upcoming new feature that someone accidentally turned on...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That review is in alpha and it is for SE employees only. So this queue is not out yet for reviewers.

Source from [this deleted question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212021/question-tagged-for-link-validation-with-no-highlighted-links#comment681886_212021)

[image]